# Selecting overload to reference-accepting function

Tags: c++, reference, overloading

In the following code I'm defining two overloads, one accepting an integer and the other a reference to an integer...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int)  { printf("foo(int)\n"); }
void foo(int&) { printf("foo(int&)\n"); }
```

Then I'm trying to call the two overloads

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    foo(3);     // Calls foo(int)
    int x = 3;
    foo(x);     // <--- compilation error (ambiguous overload)
    int& y = x;
    foo(y);     // <--- still ambiguous
    return 0;
}
```

The question is... how can the `int&` overload be selected?

If it cannot be called, what is the point of compiling it?

Comment: `static_cast<void(*)(int&)>(foo)(x);`

Comment: Maybe not direct dupe, since you're also asking why, but highly [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368474/ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function-int-and-int)

Comment: Why add complexity to the grammar by demanding a diagnostic simply for the overloads existence? Those are still two valid overloads. The problem is at the call site (with ways around it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can the `int&` overload be selected?

Using a function pointer:

```
using fptr = void (*)(int&);
fptr f = foo;
int i;
f(i);
```

---

And for those who wander here, looking for a way to overload lvalues and rvalues sensibly, the solution is to use rvalue references:

```
void foo(int&&) { printf("foo(int&&)\n"); }
void foo(int&)  { printf("foo(int&)\n"); }
```